# Limit that uses a convergent sequence as a variable

Tags: limits

Given that $a_n$ is sequence which converges to $3$ and $\forall n: a_n > 3$. Find the limit: $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{a_n^3 -2 a_n^2 - a_n - 6}{\sqrt{6 + a_n} - \sqrt{2a_n + 3}}$. What I tried was setting $a_n = 3 + \frac{1}{n}$ because the original sequence was arbitrary and this one obeyed the rules set for it. The problem is that once I rewrote the whole thing in terms of $n$ instead of $a_n$ the bottom part ended up becoming $\sqrt{9 + 1/n} - \sqrt{9 + 2/n}$ which is equal to $0$ for $n\rightarrow\infty$. And that's where I got stuck. Please help!

Comment: Picking a specific sequence when it is supposed to be arbitrary won't prove anything. Essentially this is just the limit $a\to 3^+$ so you should treat it that way.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I'm really not sure how I'm supposed to solve the limit when I don't know what the original sequence is.

Comment: It doesn't matter...? If you don't understand what I meant by the comment please ask more clarifying questions. I said to treat the $a_n$ as a variable, you can call it $x$ if you want if that's easier to see for some reason. That way the limit is $$\lim_{x\to3^+}\frac{x^3-x^2-x-6}{\sqrt{6+x}-\sqrt{2x+3}}$$

Comment: @NinadMunshi Oh I get it now. So the limit is $-\infty$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n^3 - 2a_n^2 - a_n - 6}{\sqrt{6 + a_n} - \sqrt{2a_n + 3}} = \lim_{a_n\to3^+} \frac{a_n^3 - 2a_n^2 - a_n - 6}{\sqrt{6 + a_n} - \sqrt{2a_n + 3}} = \lim_{a_n\to3^+} \frac{a_n^3 - 2a_n^2 - a_n - 6}{\sqrt{6 + a_n} - \sqrt{2a_n + 3}} \frac{\sqrt{6 + a_n} + \sqrt{2a_n + 3}}{\sqrt{6 + a_n} + \sqrt{2a_n + 3}} = \lim_{a_n\to3^+} \frac{(a_n - 3)(a_n^2 + a_n + 2)(\sqrt{6 + a_n} + \sqrt{2a_n + 3})}{3 - a_n} = -\lim_{a_n\to3^+} (a_n^2 + a_n + 2)(\sqrt{6 + a_n} + \sqrt{2a_n + 3}) = -(9 + 3 + 2)6 = -14\cdot6 = -84$

Answer (score 0):

Just a heads up, I'm using shortened notation for limits, namely $\lim_n x_n = \lim_{n\to\infty}x_n$. Given convergent sequences $(x_n), (y_n)$ we know

1. $\lim_n ax_n + by_n = a\lim_n x_n + b\lim_n y_n$
2. $\lim_n x_ny_n = (\lim_n x_n)(\lim_n y_n)$
3. if $\forall n: y_n\neq 0$ and $\lim_n y_n\neq 0$, then $\lim_n \frac{x_n}{y_n} = \frac{\lim_n x_n}{\lim_n y_n}$
4. for any continuous function $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ we know $\lim_n f(x_n) = f(\lim_n x_n)$

this should allow you to compute the limit easily, as $\sqrt{\cdot}\colon\mathbb{R^+}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^+$.

Edit: You should also consider using L'Hospital, since the original expression converges against the indeterminate expression $\frac{0}{0}$.

Using L'Hospital, you can directly utilize the comment from @Ninad Munshi.